# Reading ifstream to char* for both int and string conversion

Tags: c++, parsing, binaryfiles

I am having some trouble parsing a binary data file with the following which reads the first line

```
int LineLength = 300;
int Offset= 4586;
ifstream ifn("BinaryFile.bin");
char* line = new char[LineLength];
ifn.seekg(Offset);
while (ifn.good())
{
    ifn.read(line, LineLength);
}   
for (int i = 0; i < LineLength; i++)
    printf("%02X ", line[i]);
```

This is printing out:

```
00 FFFFFFDD 01 00 00 22 FFFFFFB0 01 00 03 4F 50 2D 31 01 31 32 33
```

When I use a hex editor to see the original data, it looks like this:

```
00 55 24 00 00 F4 BC 01 00 03 4F 50 2D 31 01 31 32 33
```

I really don't want it to alter the data, I am needing to convert some bytes to integers, and some to strings, and some will end up as dates as well, but I am having some real challenges.

```
string* DataType= new string[3]{ "int","int","string" };
int*  StartingPosition =new int[3] { 1,10,11 };
int*  ColumnWidth =new int[3] { 4,1,25 };       
char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");

for (string Name : DataType) {
    std::vector<char> CurrentColumnBytes(ColumnWidth);
    for (int C = StartingPosition; C < ColumnWidth + StartingPosition; ++C)
    {
        int Index = C - StartingPosition;       
        CurrentColumnBytes[Index] = line[C];
    }
    if (DataType == "int") {
        // still working out how to get a little endian result from 2-4 bytes if I use char
        // since it is combining bytes as shown above
    }
    if (DataType == "string") {
        for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = CurrentColumnBytes.begin(); i != CurrentColumnBytes.end(); ++i)
            std::cout << *i;
    }
}
```

I tried using `wchar_t` and `wint_t` instead of `char` as the type. With `wint_t` I was able to convert multiple bytes to a little endian int, but then I can't seem to get a string out of it.

For what it is worth, I also tried using the following where I was able to get the integers, but not the strings.

```
int LineLength = 300;
int counter = 0;
wchar_t* line = new wchar_t[LineLength];
while ((c = fgetwc("BinaryFile.bin")) != WEOF) {
    line[counter] = c;
    counter++;
    if (counter > LineLength - 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that you need to read the file into an `unsigned char vector` / array. Also don't use `fgetwc` or you will only get every other byte, AND it detects when there are multiple null bytes in a row and combines them which can throw off your count. `Ifstream` didn't seem to have a simple way to read only part of the file into an `unsigned char vector`

```
int LineLength = 300;
int counter = 0;
std::vector<unsigned char> line(LineLength);
while ((c = fgetw("BinaryFile.bin")) != WEOF) {
    line[counter] = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
    counter++;
    if (counter > LineLength - 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Then once you have it in the vector, you can handle the data separately

```
for (string Name : DataType) { // here just looping over the columns that were defined in the JSON file - excluding some things that aren't relevant
{
    char* locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8");
    std::vector<unsigned char> CurrentColumnBytes(ColumnWidth);     
    for (int C = StartingPosition; C < ColumnWidth + StartingPosition; ++C)
    {
        int Index = C - StartingPosition;       
        CurrentColumnBytes[Index] = BufferedLine[C];
    }
    if (DataType == "int") {    
        cout << DataParser::LEByte(CurrentColumnBytes); //custom function that tests length, converts to Little Endian int from the individual bytes.
    }
    if (DataType == "string") {
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnWidth; i++)
            cout<<CurrentColumnBytes[i];
    }
    cout<<" | ";    
}
```